# Where to host source code for a small client project?

Tags: web-development, clients

I'm about to start work on a small client project and I'm not sure where to host the source code.

It seems silly to suggest to them to create a private Github repo on the paid tier, since it's a project of such a small scale.

I've been thinking of hosting the code as a private repo on my own personal Github account. The idea seems wrong right off the bat, so I wanted to hear your opinion on the matter.

Also - gitlab/bitbucket are out of the question because of the continuous deployment I have set up for my hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Many factors could be considered:

What would be most practical for the client? How IT-savvy are they? If they have zero IT people employed, perhaps delivering the code on a USB-stick is preferable. If they do have other IT - or perhaps could benefit from having multiple repositiories at Github, that could be a more modern option. In addition, it would easilier enable remote work - which may or may not be relevant.

What would be in line with your ambitions towards the client? If this is a one-time solution and you don't expect further income, perhaps the USB-stick is fine. If more projects are forthcoming, setting up a client-owned infrastructure for that seems reasonable.

There is off course also the 'protectionist' angle, where a freelancer seeks to prevent the client from employing another freelancer. In that case, using your own Github account would be the way to go. In time, the client might feel held at ransom by you - so that approach is usually at best short-sighted.

Answer (score 0):

For small projects maybe VisualStudioOnline is worth considering. It's free up to 5 users, gives private repos, wiki, task management and basic CI/CD.
Maybe UI and capabilities aren't equal to Github's, but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to create a new project on Google Cloud and use their source control.  Free for up to 5 projects a month.

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/